# JavaScript filter with includes gives error if string is null

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I use the filter method on my list to search whether a string contains a substring it gives the error Cannot read property 'includes' of null. Which is totally understandable because my list contains some null elements.

How can I solve this  so that the filter does not use include on the null values?

```
this.list = this.list.filter(i => i.user.includes(this.searchUser))
```

I can filter out the null elements first and then filter again on the new list, but then I have to filter twice.. Anyway to avoid this?

In C# you can simply use the ?. operator user?.includes but in JavaScript it is not possible?

Comment: There is **[a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)** to add that operator into JS.  In the meantime, it's relatively easy to write your own function to handle the null-checking over a path.

Comment: Also ["C#'s Null-conditional operator" Typescript proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8690) added to the answer.

Comment: But also consider whether the extra filtering actually hurts anything.  It would be quite readable: `list.filter(notNull).filter(has('user')).filter(i => i.user.includes(this.searchUser))`.  It it performs to your requirements, why not stick with the simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common, but not pretty way, of checking all steps in the chain:

```
this.list = this.list
    .filter(i => (i && i.user && i.user.includes(this.searchUser)))
```

[C#'s Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) has been proposed to be added to [Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8690) and [Javascript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).